# Show that the infinite series is divergent (Alternate solutions)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

The question is to find whether the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {(p+1)(p+2)...(p+n)}{(q+1)(q+2)...(q+n)},$$ given that $q<p+1,$ is convergent (absolutely or conditionally) or divergent.
I have already succeeded on proving that this is divergent through the Corollary of the Raabe's test. But I would like to ask some hints on how to use other possible methods and maybe a shorter proof since mine is quite lengthy though. (especially Limit Comparison Test) maybe on the series that I would compare it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $q < p+1$,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(p+1)(p+2)\dots(p+n)}{(q+1)(q+2)\dots (q+n)}
&> \frac{(p+1)(p+2)\dots(p+n)}{(p+1+1)(p+1+2)\dots (p+1+n)} \\
&= \frac{(p+1)(p+2)\dots(p+n)}{(p+2)(p+3)\dots (p+n+1)} \\
&= \frac{p+1}{p+n+1} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{p}{n}
\end{align}$$
so the series diverges by comparison with the Harmonic series.